# Unable to open a file on local sever

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, htdocs

While writing '**localhost**' as url in the browser, the **index.html** at this location runs: `**file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PrepLift/html/index.php**`

Generally, writing localhost as url in a browser, the index.html file saved at htdocs runs. But in my case index.html kept at other location runs.

If i want to run a index.html file kept in htdocs, what i should write as url?

let's suppose I want to run this file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/wp_blog/accesspress-lite/index.php on the browser using localhost. (This file is in some other branch folders saved in htdocs). What url should I write?

As the target file which I want to run is in the folder before the location of index.html running by localhost.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. You talk about localhost, yet you're showing file:// URI's, they're not the same. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: From what I understand from your question is that you need to create an virtual directory alias to your wp_blog folder to be able to access it through apache

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Server and open on http protocol ... file protocol will not execute php code

You are using xampp. So run it and access it at something 
http://localhost/wp_blog/ ( if your port is not 80 than 
http://localhost:PORT_NO/wp_blog/
for example PORT_NO = 8000
than http://localhost:8000/wp_blog/

You can also run default php server like this (if php is available globally):
Go to public folder -> open cmd -> Type "php -S localhost:8000"

Comment: actually the wp_blog folder is not in the root directory. I have been using http protocol instead of file protocol. And there is no issue with the port. I think there is a need to create a virtual directory to wp_blog folder.